# Как сделать, чтобы через определённое время ожидания input() компьютер высылал ещё одно письмо?

Tags: python, python-3.x, время

У меня есть игра с личными кабинетами, и мне бы хотелось, чтобы, когда пользователь при регистрации не вводит код из письма **1** минуту, ему отсылалось 2-е письмо.

**P. S. письма знаю как отправлять**

Comment: В отдельном треде `input` сделать, подождать минуту что тред завершился, если не завершился, то убить его и послать письмо.

Comment: С помощью модуля `Thread`?

Comment: Ну, например. Есть ещё варианты в принципе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [тут](https://coderoad.ru/19508353/Python-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-10-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82) есть вся нужная Вам информация. На этой веб-странице есть даже несколько вариантов решения Вашей задачи.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, @Anaconda (или Grand IT)

Comment: Рад, что помог! Называйте меня Anaconda :)